# Testing a migration with `try-runtime`

Tags: migration, try-runtime

I have written a migration for the phragmen pallet in Substrate and now I want to test it. I would want to use the current state of Kusama/Polkadot to make sure the migration works correctly. To achieve this AFAIU I need to use the `try-runtime` feature.

I have a problem and a question regarding the `try-runtime` feature.

1. When I specify the `--uri` argument to be equal to `wss://rpc.polkadot.io`(as provided in the documentation) I get the following error:

```
2022-12-03 10:28:32 error: "`WsClientBuilder` failed to build: Transport(Invalid URL: No port number in URL (default port is not supported))"    
Error: Input("failed to build ws client")
```

2. When running the `on-runtime-upgrade` subcommand which runtime upgrade is being executed and how can I specify it so that it executes the `on_runtime_upgrade` function that I have wrote for my migration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question! `try-runtime` is the right idea indeed. (Note for Parity devs at the end)

Currently the try-runtime CLI scraps the chain state from the an RPC node. Using the public node is probably really slow.
This is the procedure I use with success:

0. Write a new migration in Substrate, eg `MyMigration`.
1. Integrate the migration into the runtime by adding it to the `Executive` type. This needs to be done for all runtimes where you want the migration to execute.
   Example from [Kusama](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/bc65cf22a359859c20bc4aae94bcffad1846d5b6/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L1466):

```rust
pub type Executive = frame_executive::Executive<
    Runtime,
    Block,
    frame_system::ChainContext<Runtime>,
    Runtime,
    AllPalletsWithSystem,
    (
        MyMigration, // Added here
        SomeOtherMigration
    ),
>;
```

2. Run [diener](https://github.com/paritytech/diener/) in the Polkadot repo to patch your Substrate version:

```bash
# If you have it on a branch:
diener update --substrate --branch tmp-oty-debug-bench-bot-revert
# ... or in a local folder:
diener patch --crates-to-patch ../substrate --substrate
```

3. Build a release binary with the `try-runtime` feature. So for example: `cargo b -r --bin polkadot --features try-runtime`.
4. Start a local Polkadot node by using the current [release binary](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases). This node will be used instead of a public endpoint to speed things up tremendously. The node requires some extra arguments. This works well for me (could probably be optimized):

```bash
./polkadot --chain polkadot --db paritydb -d empty-dir/ --sync warp --rpc-max-request-size 100000 --rpc-max-response-size 100000 --rpc-external --rpc-cors=all --unsafe-ws-external
```

Wait until you see `Warp sync is complete`. Which looks like this:

```
⏩ Warping, Importing state, 1044.21 Mib (32 peers), best: #15600673 (0xef7d…adca), finalized #15600673 (0xef7d…adca), ⬇ 13.8kiB/s ⬆ 0.7kiB/s    
Warp sync is complete (1044 MiB), restarting block sync.    
⏩ Block history, #2688 (32 peers), best: #15600705 (0x53c2…55b1), finalized #15600701 (0x55fc…001a), ⬇ 958.7kiB/s ⬆ 18.3kiB/s
```

5. Start the `try-runtime` CLI from your locally build binary in a second terminal with the same chain-spec:

```bash
RUST_LOG=remote-ext=debug,runtime=trace ./target/release/polkadot try-runtime --chain=polkadot-dev --execution=Wasm --no-spec-check-panic on-runtime-upgrade live --uri ws://localhost:9944
```

This will first download the whole state from your local node and then run all migrations. Should look like this:

```
# Lots of these:
DEBUG main remote-ext: new total = 241000, full page received: …

# Lots of these:
DEBUG main remote-ext: progress = 0.05 [40000 / 806314] …

# Then the interesting part:
main polkadot_runtime: try-runtime::on_runtime_upgrade polkadot

# Then you will see the log output of your migrations
# Finally if it was successful: 
main try-runtime::cli: TryRuntime_on_runtime_upgrade executed without errors. 
Consumed weight = (83471000 ps, 0 byte), total weight = (2000000000000 ps, 5242880 byte) (0.00 %, 0.00 %).
```

6. Repeat steps 4 and 5 for all runtimes by changing the `--chain` arguments.

Note: If you are a Parity dev you can use the try-runtime bot. Usage looks like [this](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/6297#issuecomment-1329160666).
In the future the try-runtime checks will run automatically on all Polkadot MRs in the CI, which should make manual testing superfluous.